# How does the "where()" work in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

When learning SQLAlchemy, the `where()` clause in a query works like a magic since it expresses things quite naturally.
However, I couldn't understand why it works in this way.

Consider this query:

```
.where(MyTable.MyColumn == 1)
```

In theory, the parameter passed in Python is its value (reference could be considered as pointer value from my perspective), so `MyTable.MyColumn == 1` is estimated (as a value) and then passed to the function. However, how this function behaves is like "estimating the value when executing the actual query" (i.e. just like a real SQL WHERE clause).

I understand a similar behavior in NumPy (e.g. `np.argwhere(myarray > 0)`) is achieved by returning the boolean value of each element estimated in this condition and then performing actions on it. E.g. `np.asarray([[0,1,2],[1,2,0]]) > 0` would result in `array([[False,True,True],[True,True,False]], dtype=bool)` and `np.argwhere()` simply operates on this value. I think SQLAlchemy may use a similar technique, but I still couldn't think out how they actually achieved it.

Could anyone give a brief explanation on why and how it works?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators for some insight as to how and what SQLAlchemy overloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Overloading

I bet that `MyTable.MyColumn` overrides `__eq__`. `a == b` is essentially the same as `a.__eq__(b)`.

So, `MyTable.MyColumn` just has to override `__eq__` to return a selector object rather than a bool.

Overloading Example: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxCoAgFIXh3ac4NCm0RJvQ0JNI1BUFMdPb0NPbHRo62893ysPhzHPve9paw2oVZAd5OBdzZOd0o@SNRRH/IV0fjTg5UJVHJb5rxhDioNSGBas2qtSYWUstmEzvLw)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand what overloadding is, but was just confused about how they did it. Returning a selector makes a lot sense :)

Comment: @renyuneyun No problem! Yeah, returning an unconventional value (non-`bool`) from `__eq__` is really confusing and threw me off at first but then I realized that you can do anything with this sort of stuff if you want (I do code-golf, which frequently abuses language's capabilities :P)